# What are these called? a pillar and a wooden bed?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Look at the picture. This is a room in a high-sky building for children to play. It was designed like in the picture.

[image]

There is a wooden platform for people to sit or lie on. Should we call it "**a wooden bed**" or "**a wooden stage**" ?

Also, there are many wooden supporting sticks. Should we call it "**a pillar**"

> **[​pillar](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pillar?q=pillar)**: a large round stone, metal or wooden post that is used to support a bridge, the roof of a building, etc., especially
>   when it is also decorative
>
> *Two white marble pillars stood on either side of the entrance.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The vertical objects that extend from the floor to the ceiling are pillars or columns. The flat raised surface is a platform.

A stage is a platform where people perform. A bed is a place where people lie down and/or sleep. It doesn't appear that the platform in your photo has either of these functions.